# why is call to ssh with Python subprocess breaking outer bash loop

Tags: python, bash, ssh, subprocess

I have a bash script `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    myprog.py
done
```

calling a python program `myprog.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output(['ssh', 'user@host', 'cmd'])
```

The ssh command that is called by subprocess executes without error, the output is correct. But when called like this the loop in `myscript.sh` only runs through the first line of input and then exits with status 0.  If I replace the `subprocess.check_output(...)` call with a `subprocess.Popen(...)` and *don't* subsequently call `Popen.wait()` then the outer loop works as expected and the output from the `ssh` command is dumped to standard out some time after any output from the bash script.  With the `Popen.wait()` behavior is the same as with `check_output`: bash loop only goes through one iteration before exiting without error.

If instead of `ssh` another command, e.g. `ls`, is called with `check_output` then the bash loop works as expected.

Can anyone help me understand why the code as shown isn't working as expected?

Note: this is a simplified version of what I am trying to do, though I do experience the same behavior with this code.  In reality I am doing something with "$line" in the bash script and the subprocess call is wrapped in a `try`/`except` block.

Comment: Educated guess: the `ssh` process is eating up standard input. Try passing `stdin=open("/dev/null")` to `check_output`.

Comment: thanks @larsmans I had roughly the same thought at the same time.  Addding the -n argument to the ssh command does the trick!

Answer (score 3):

As @larsmans guessed the `ssh` call was consuming stdin, breaking the outer bash loop.  Adding the `-n` option to the `ssh` command resolved the issue:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['ssh', '-n', 'user@host', 'cmd'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that ssh reads from standard input, therefore it "eats" all the remaining lines in the loop. You can just connect its standard input to nowhere using the `-n` flag:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['ssh', '-n', 'user@host', 'cmd'])
```

Look for the details on the man pages of ssh here https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh and https://man.openbsd.org/ssh